# Translation and transliteration of Prophets saying

Tags: prophet-muhammad, arabic

Majed Mahmoud has a talk in which he mentions [something that the Prophet (PBUH) used to say](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXROtfM14Qw&feature=youtu.be&t=255).

I would like it if somebody can provide a translation and transliteration of this please.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take some time to learn more about this site and our model by taking the 2 min. [tour] and visiting our [help].

Comment: I guess you mean الحمد لله على كل حال al-hamdolillah 'ala kulli hal see also in sunan ibn Majah (with transliteration) https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/148 and Jami' at-tirmidhihttps://sunnah.com/urn/729510

Answer (score 1):

Just as asyncBoy has said, praise to Allah in any case.

There's a similar saying in Arabic: *نحمده علی بلائه کما نحمده علی الائه*

*praise to Allah for his tests (struggles we go through) **just as** we praise Allah in his blessings.*

When you're child is sick, praise the lord the he's just not sicker, that he's a Muslim, praise the lord that you're at least married and with child (many don't get married, many are divorce, many can't have children, many have dead children, etc.)

When you have a bad spouse, still praise the lord for all the good things you were able to achieve because of this spouse...you were able to have amazing children you will able to pious, enjoy a bed together, your sustenance was increased together...

Answer (score 0):

When something bad happen to you "praise Allah **on any case** ."

You praise Allah always for good things that why to add ".. on any case" on bad thing happen .